# What are stacking contexts and how do they move forward and backward?

Tags: html, css

I'm reading [this](http://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/) article right now and it describes stacking contexts.

What I don't understand is, what does the author mean by "that move forward and backward"?
How do elements move forward and backward?

Comment: It sounds like by "forward" he means "z-index increases", and likewise for "backward"

Comment: I believe @JasonBaker is correct. Z-indexes also can only be used on elements that have a position defined like Relative, Fixed, or Absolute.

Answer (score 0):

By forward and backward, they mean in space, as in: the perception of things overlapping each other in space and giving the illusion that they are in front of and behind each other.

Just for an added bonus, you can play with z-index in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JMC_Creative/j70suerL/).

ignore below.

```
<div>
```